# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner and also a diploma student...
    please help me solve this error... I tried many online solution but it cant help ... I'm new to php and mysql...

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="slr"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="software"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
// Get values from form 
$soft_name=$_POST['soft_name'];
$installed_date=$_POST['installed_date'];
$expiry_date=$_POST['expiry_date'];
$product_key=$_POST['product_key'];
// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $software(soft_name, installed_date, expiry_date, product_key)VALUES('$soft_name', '$installed_date', '$expiry_date', '$product_key')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
    echo "Successful";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<a href='CreateData.php'>Back to main page</a>";
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Are you using xAMP ?..

I suppose that mysql is not enabled

Comment: how to enable it... please help me...

Comment: Before, I just had an other idea, try with `mysqli_connect` instead of `mysql_connect` which is deprecated since PHP 5.5.0 (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

Comment: Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SLR\CreateData2.php on line 11
cannot select DB

Comment: i have changed it as above and it give a warning...

Comment: I post my full response as an Answer. Please tell me if everything is ok. if so, check it as solved answer

Comment: i still have error...

Answer (score 3):

You should use `mysqli_connect` instead of `mysql_connect` which is deprecated since PHP 5.5.0 :

```
    $link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysqli_select_db($link, $db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SLR\CreateData2.php on line 21
ERROR 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_close() in C:\xampp\htdocs\SLR\CreateData2.php:37 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SLR\CreateData2.php on line 37

Comment: Same as others.. Use **mysqli_close($link);** Take a look at this example in offical php documentation : http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.select-db.php ("Procedural style" example)

Comment: now it shows:
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SLR\CreateData2.php on line 21
ERROR 
Warning: mysqli_close() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SLR\CreateData2.php on line 37

Comment: Got to official php doc, it is really well written :  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php. You have to pass `$link` param too, so  : `$result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);` where `$link` is the same variable as my answer (your connection to DB)

Comment: Nice ! Please check my answer as the right one, thanks. And read PHP official doc, there are helpful examples

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

**Old way**:

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
    mysql_select_db('testdb', $link);
    mysql_set_charset('UTF-8', $link);
?>
```

**New way**: all you gotta do is create a new PDO object. PDO's constructor takes at most 4 parameters, DSN, username, password, and an array of driver options.

A DSN is basically a string of options that tell PDO which driver to use, and the connection details... You can look up all the options here [PDO MYSQL DSN](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php)

```
<?php
    $db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=slr;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', '') or die("Could connect to Database");
?>
```

According to [Here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).